# permission denied error when deploying Web App in Azure

Tags: node.js, azure

I am trying to deploy a web app in Azure, the build with Github Actions is successful, but then the container crashes in Azure, and I get an error about permission denied for the 'cross-env' package, which is a dependency in my package.json. The project runs fine locally.

console

```
2023-10-12T21:27:43.947743248Z 
2023-10-12T21:27:43.947747649Z npm start
2023-10-12T21:27:45.373528228Z npm info using npm@9.6.4
2023-10-12T21:27:45.373565332Z npm info using node@v18.17.1
2023-10-12T21:27:45.459141307Z 
2023-10-12T21:27:45.459175710Z > MyProject@0.0.1 start
2023-10-12T21:27:45.459182911Z > cross-env NODE_ENV=production nodemon ./bin/www
2023-10-12T21:27:45.459188211Z 
2023-10-12T21:27:45.531346836Z sh: 1: cross-env: Permission denied

2023-10-12T21:27:51.870Z ERROR - Container MyProject didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 8080, 
failing site start. 
2023-10-12T21:27:51.873Z INFO  - Stopping site MyProject because it failed during startup.
```

package.json

```
 "scripts": {
    "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production nodemon ./bin/www",
    "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development nodemon ./bin/www",
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=18.17.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
    "npm": "^9.6.4",
     "nodemon": "^1.19.0",
    ...
    ...


  },
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried using **`cross-env`** in my **`package.json`**  and added a startup command to initialize the sample nodejs express app with `cross-env`. After validating the app running successfully locally, I deployed it via Github Actions, And it ran successfully refer below:-

**Command to install cross-env locally:-**

```js
npm i cross-env
```

**My package.json:-**

```json
{
  "name": "myexpressapp",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.4",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "debug": "~2.6.9",
    "ejs": "^3.1.9",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "http-errors": "~1.6.3",
    "morgan": "~1.9.1"
  }
}
```

I pushed my local code to Github repository and deployed it via **Azure Web app Deployment Center** like below:-

[image]

**My github workflow:-**

```yaml
name: Build and deploy Node.js app to Azure Web App - valleywebapp93

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up Node.js version
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: '18.x'

      - name: npm install, build, and test
        run: |
          npm install
          npm run build --if-present
          npm run test --if-present

      - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: node-app
          path: .

  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}

    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: node-app

      - name: 'Deploy to Azure Web App'
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        with:
          app-name: 'valleywebapp93'
          slot-name: 'production'
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AzureAppService_PublishProfile_37c199061c544aaf9f9e913c30f41b97 }}
          package: .
```

**My Repository:-**

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-nodejs?tabs=linux&pivots=development-environment-vscode)

[image]

**Output:-**

[image]

[image]